# Trying to make a progress counter for a study buddy type website

Tags: javascript, html, css

The user fills out an input form with the number of pages and I want the user to be able to input the pages done (var pagesToBeSubtracted) and the function to subtract the pages and update it on the site.

```
function subtractPages() {
 // Total pages that are grabbed from the input form
var totalPages = document.getElementById("numPages").value;

//Value of the input type number for done pages
var pagesToBeSubtracted = document.getElementById("donePages").value;

var remainingPages;

remainingPages = totalPages - pagesToBeSubtracted;

//Updating the number on the actual website
document.getElementById("pagesLeft").innerHTML = remainingPages;
```

However if you have total pages at 100 and you put that you did 5 pages it will go to 95 but if you press it again it will stay the same, if you bump it to 10 it will go down to 90 etc...

I get I should somehow save the result so that the next time the function is called, it doesn't start from the original number every time but from the updated one. But I can't figure out how to do it since I set the variable for total pages from the input form and every time the function is called it sets it at the same number again.

I'm sure I'm missing something elementary but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can just store the `remainingPages` "globally" i.e. not inside a function

Comment: Still the subtraction is weird, if I put I did 5 pages and run it it goes down from 100 to 95, but if I run it with 5 again, it stays at 95 it doesnt go down to 90.

Comment: Something like this should work: https://jsfiddle.net/1fbow8re/

Comment: yes, that is, because you're probably still using `remainingPages = totalPages - pagesToBeSubtracted;` inside your function. Try `remainingPages -= pagesToBeSubtraced` instead and don't forget to set `var remainingPages = totalPages` at the beginning of your program.

Comment: @Turnip your example does work, however you can't change the input, it only works on the value you set beforehand since it gives me an error that I can't grab value of null

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Does this solve the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/1n36wyf2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might be looking for the same solution, @Turnip did it I'm just copying and pasting his jsfiddle so that anyone next that comes can just see it.

https://jsfiddle.net/1n36wyf2/

```
var remainingPages = document.getElementById("numPages").value;

document.getElementById("btnSubtract").addEventListener("click", subtractPages);

// Update `remainingPages` when `#numPages` changes.
document.getElementById("numPages").addEventListener("input", function() {
remainingPages = this.value;
});

function subtractPages() {
var pagesToBeSubtracted = document.getElementById("donePages").value; 

remainingPages = remainingPages - pagesToBeSubtracted;

//Updating the number on the actual website
document.getElementById("pagesLeft").innerHTML = remainingPages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your user submit value in the input form, you can use localStorage to save that value. You can then access that value on user revisit to your website. localStorage store data locally within the user's browser. The data will not be deleted when the browser/computer is closed.

You can store a value by using setItem method of localStorage:

```
 localStorage.setItem("totalPages", numberOfTotalPages);
 localStorage.setItem("pagesToBeSubtracted", numberOfPagesToBeSubtracted);
```

You can get a stored value by using getItem method of localStorage

```
document.getElementById("pagesLeft").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("totalPages")-localStorage.getItem("pagesToBeSubtracted");
```